# Bidirectional Communication between Python and C#

Tags: python, c#, ipc, named-pipes

I'm working on a project, where I have to connect Python and C# in a rather flexible way, with information being send from one to the other frequently. Most of the time, the data goes back and forth (A works with data, sends result to B, B works with result, answers A) but not necessary always.

Named pipes seemed like the way to go but I'm struggling with keeping it all synchronous.

Currently I'm just starting a server on one of them and let it wait for a client connection, while the other creates a server as well, and connects as a client when the server is ready.
It's a lot of creating servers and clients and trying to not break it, which happens as soon as a client tries to connect to an not existing server..

I'd like to do it with a pipe that runs in a separate thread, but couldn't find a way to keep it alive, it simply closes, when the client is done reading.

Are named pipes just too simplistic for such a task, or is there a way to make this work robustly?

Update:
For reference, how my code looks like (reduced to the minimum here):

First the NamedPipe Server and Client in C#

```
public static void SendDataToPython(string payload)
{
    using (var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("Test"))
    {
        server.WaitForConnection();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(payload);
            server.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
        }

        server.Disconnect();
    }
}



public static string WaitForMessage()
{
    string message = "";
    string servername = ".";
    string pipeName = "CSServer";
    using (var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(servername, pipeName, PipeDirection.In))
    {
        pipeClient.Connect();
```

And in Python:

```
class PipeServer():
    def __init__(self, pipeName):
        self.pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
            r'\\.\pipe\\' + pipeName,
            win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
            1, 65536, 65536,
            0,
            None)

    def connect(self):
        win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(self.pipe, None)

    def write(self, message):
        win32file.WriteFile(self.pipe, message.encode() + b'\n')

    def close(self):
        win32file.CloseHandle(self.pipe)

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient))
            {
                string temp;
                while ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    message += temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return message;
    }

class PipeClient:
    def __init__(self, pipeName):
        self.pipeName = pipeName

    def receive(self):
        file_handle = win32file.CreateFile(
            f"\\\\.\\pipe\\{self.pipeName}",
            win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            None,
            win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            None)
        left, data = win32file.ReadFile(file_handle, 4096)
        print(data.decode("utf-8")[1:])
```

Comment: "Creating a server" how? TCP sockets? Maybe look into ZeroMQ or gRPC if not a simple RESTful JSON API over HTTP

Comment: Eventually "gRPC" could help you

Comment: @OneCricketeer "Creating a server" using Named Pipes, as mentioned. In C# with the aptly named NamedPipeServerStream. Maybe "Creating" is not the appropriate word, sorry if that is the case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, so its unclear to me how Python would know the "name of the named pipe" in order to connect with it (do you have code already doing this you can share?). Otherwise, sounds like you want a language agnostic solution such as the ones mentioned

Comment: Code now included. Client and Server recognize each other by sharing the same name (on the local machine). The offered solutions definitely look good, but I will have to read into them first.